# Using AJAX get method to retrieve data from a page that has additional loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I’m wanting to use an AJAX get method to retrieve contents from a page URL. The method works fine, the issue I’m getting is that call returns data before the page is completely loaded

Is there a way I can have the AJAX call only retrieve contents after say 5 seconds for example? (To ensure the page is fully loaded)

You can see on the page below, the page loads and then an additional loading symbol appears which loads the content. I want to retrieve the page data once all content has been loaded

https://pool.pm/addr1qy2465r5axxz92f0rlfyymz5zvsxad2v038slu70qeegm4aac2mvf8qqsgva9exmwhwpxymt896v5anudtr2wee77y6qgudr8k

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) global event handler. The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

For example

```
window.onload = function() {
  doSomething();
};
```

And if you need to do the call after 5 secs, do the following

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    doSomething();
  }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but I'm still getting the same response in the console. Am i doing something wrong? i've saved a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/9re8km7j/

Comment: @Namenone the URL you use leads to a WEB site page. You receive the page as response as expected. Probably you need something else. Maybe you need to query some API instead, to get info about that cryptocurrency wallet?